A contradiction in deriving Cramer's theorem in this application?
Setup: We have two bernoulli distributions with parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively. We need to draw $T$ samples in all from both the distribution. It is done in the following way:

Sample $w_1T/2$ samples from $Ber(p_1)$ and sample $(1-w_1)T/2$ samples from $Ber(p_2)$ with $w_1 \in (0,1)$ a fixed constant.
Observe the sample means $\bar{X}_{1,T/2}$ and $\bar{X}_{2,T/2}$. Based on the sample means $\bar{X}_{1,T/2},\bar{X}_{2,T/2}$ we decide $w_2(\bar{X}_{1,T/2},\bar{X}_{2,T/2})$ as the sampling proportions for the next period. Assume that $1-\epsilon \geq w_2 \geq \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \in (0,1/4]$ a fixed constant.
Sample $w_2(\bar{X}_{1,T/2},\bar{X}_{2,T/2})T/2$ samples from $Ber(p_1)$ and $(1-w_2(\bar{X}_{1,T/2},\bar{X}_{2,T/2}))T/2$ samples from $Ber(p_2)$.
Let the observed sample averages in the second period be $\bar{Y}_{1,T/2}$ and $\bar{Y}_{2,T/2}$ respectively.

Goal: Derive an LDP for $(\bar{X}_{1,T/2},\bar{X}_{2,T/2},\bar{Y}_{1,T/2},\bar{Y}_{2,T/2})$ as $T \to \infty$.
Method 1: Method of types using the approach given in Theorem 2.7 of the notes:1
We use the method of types (since we know the conditional distribution of $\bar{Y}_{1,T/2},\bar{Y}_{2,T/2}$ given $\bar{X}_{1,T/2},\bar{X}_{2,T/2})$. We can derive an intuitive looking rate function  of the form:
$$
I(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=\frac{w_1 D(x_1||p_1)+(1-w_1)D(x_2||p_2)+w_2(x_1,x_2)D(y_1||p_1)+(1-w_2(x_1,x_2))D(y_2||p_2)}{2}
$$
Method 2: *Using Gartner Ellis approach given in Theorem 4.2 of the notes:1.
For the full argument see my previous question given here:2. There we derived the following rate function:
$$
\Lambda(\lambda_{1,x},\lambda_{2,x},\lambda_{1,y},\lambda_{2,y})=\underset{x_1,x_2}{sup}\left(\lambda_{1,x} x_1+\lambda_{2,x}x_2+\frac{w_2(x_1,x_2)(p_1e^{2\lambda_{1,y}/w_2}+1-p_1)+(1-w_2(x_1,x_2))(p_2e^{2\lambda_{2,y}/(1-w_2)}+1-p_2)}{2} -\left(\frac{w_1 D(x_1||p_1)+(1-w_1)D(x_2||p_2)}{2}\right)\right)
$$
The fenchel conjugate/ rate function of this limiting cumulant function then is:
$$
I(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=\underset{\lambda_{1,x},\lambda_{2,x},\lambda_{1,y},\lambda_{2,y}}{sup}\lambda_{1,x}x_1+\lambda_{2,x}x_2+\lambda_{1,y}y_1+\lambda_{2,y}y_2-\Lambda(\lambda_{1,x},\lambda_{2,x},\lambda_{1,y},\lambda_{2,y})
$$
Question Why does the two approaches give very different large deviation rate functions? As I show here Gartner Ellis approach gives an upper bound on the method of type approach. Why is there an apparent mismatch in the rate function. I think large deviation theory tells us that the rate function must be unique.
